# Yii2 dataprovider with manytomany relation

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I try to build a grid view with many-to-many relations. So I need a query for the `ActiveDataProvider` .

I have a table 'ressource', a table 'type' and between them a table 'historique'.

I have the good relation in my models but I don't know how to create the dataProvider.

In my model Ressource :

```
public function getHistorique()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Historique::className(), ['idType' => 'idType']);
}



public function getType()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Type::className(), ['idType' => 'idType'])
        ->viaTable(Historique::className(), ['idRessource' => 'idRessource']);   
}
```

In my model Historique :

```
public function getType()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Type::className(), ['idType' => 'idType']);
}

public function getRessource()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Ressource::className(), ['idRessource' => 'idRessource']);
}
```

and finally in my model Type :

```
public function getHistorique()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Historique::className(), ['idType' => 'idType']);
}
public function getRessource()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ressource::className(), ['idRessource' => 'idRessource'])
        ->viaTable(Historique::className(), ['idType' => 'idType']);
}
```

So in the Controller (in fact my ModelSearch), I want to have ressources with type from the table historique. I don't know what I have to add after

```
Ressource::find();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you use `RessourceSearch()->search()` method. So inside it you have something like this:

```
$query = Ressource::find();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);

if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
  return $dataProvider;
}

// Here is list of searchable fields of your model.
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
      ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'auth_key', $this->auth_key])


return $dataProvider;
```

So, basically, you need to add additional `Where` you your query and force to join relation table. You can do that using `joinWith` method to join additional relation and `andFilterWhere` using `table.field` notation for adding filter parameters. For example:

```
$query = Ressource::find();
$query->joinWith(['historique', 'type']);
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type.type', $this->type]);
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'historique.historique_field', $this->historique_field]);
```

Also do not forget to add rules for additional filters in your search model. For example above, you should add to your `rules()` array something like that:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // here add attributes rules from Ressource model
            [['historique_field', 'type'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
```

You can use any additional validation rules for that fields

Comment: Thanks I wasn't close. I have just a last question : In the gridView when i use GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]) it works. But when I want to select just some columns in the grid view attributes from others table than ressource are unknown. What should I have to write in attribute from the gridview ?

Comment: @SamaëlVillette you also should use dot-notation for attribute or column name  `relation.attribute`

Comment: I will try this thanks for your answer, it really helped me :)

Comment: @SamaëlVillette good luck with this :) Feel free to select answer as correct or add additional details in case of additional troubles.

Comment: I have another trouble the filter does not work : I added `$query->adnFilterWhere(['like', 'type.nomType', $this->nomType]);`

Then in the gridview I have columns like this :
`[
    'label' => 'name',
    'attribute' => 'type.nomType'
 ]`

I added some rules but THe grid view haven't any filter field

Comment: @SamaëlVillette do you mean sorting and filter input in view at top of table?

Comment: Yes that's it, I have dataGridView and filter model in the gridview but it doesn't work

Comment: @SamaëlVillette you should also set `attribute` parameter in your column config and also declare public parameter in your search model with same name

Comment: Okay but attribute in the view are like relation.attribute and in the ModelSearch they are like attribute (and public), do you think the problem come from here ?

Comment: @SamaëlVillette you can use public attribute of ModelSearch class-  to manage your filtering request and set it in 'attribute' parameter. And for view you can also use parameters of column, like` 'data' => function($model) {
return $model->relation->field;
}`